# Why can't I write Dictionary to plist?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, plist, nsdictionary

Hey All,I got a weird problem here
First I create a small project to try write dictionary to plist
I declared a textfield and a button and this is code about IBAction:

```
NSArray *localPathsTemp   = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *localDocPathTemp    = [localPathsTemp objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *localFilePathTemp   = [localDocPathTemp stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"InputPassword.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *localDictreadTemp  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:localFilePathTemp];
NSMutableDictionary *localSerialNumber = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:setSN.text
                                                                                forKey:@"input_serial_number"];
```

I try to log what I write in

```
NSLog(@"Local Dictionary : %@",[localDictreadTemp valueForKey:@"input_serial_number"]);//"input_serial_number=1"
NSLog(@"Dictionary-localSerialNumber is %@",[localSerialNumber valueForKey:@"input_serial_number"]);//1(I enter 1 at textfield)
```

It's woks fine as I think

But I move this whole to my project

I got a NULL

This is the code in my original project(in a alertview)

```
NSArray *localPathsTemp   = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *localDocPathTemp    = [localPathsTemp objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *localFilePathTemp   = [localDocPathTemp stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"InputPassword.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *localDictreadTemp  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:localFilePathTemp];
NSMutableDictionary *localSerialNumber = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:setLocalSerialNumber.text
                                                                                        forKey:@"input_serial_number"];
[localDictreadTemp addEntriesFromDictionary:localSerialNumber];
[localDictreadTemp writeToFile:localFilePathTemp atomically:YES];


NSLog(@"Text in the textfield:%@",setLocalSerialNumber.text);
NSLog(@"Local Dictionary %@",localSerialNumber);//"input_serial_number" = 1 
NSLog(@"Dictionary-LocalDictreadTemp %@",[localDictreadTemp valueForKey:@"input_serial_number"]);//NULL
```

Last result is **NULL**

That's the problem I can't figure out,I got a value at sample ,but not work here .

Why...did I give a wrong file path or ... ?

Thanks for all replys

---

More information about my project

My application is use to control a hardware device
If the user is first time to use application
User have to enter the password and device serial number
The device is use bonjour to search the device
And get a  default serial number/password from URL(this case is in WIFI)
ex.the URL is `http://11.33.44.65/defaultsn_pwd.php`

I will get a plist file like :

```
{
     sn  = 1; 
     pwd = 777;
}
```

This is the information user can't see it.
And the application will pop up an alertView with two textfields
If the text in the textfield is match the sn/pwd form URL
It will write in.
But !!!if user is in the 3G environment , It will connect to my server to control the device
This is very different with Wifi,because you have to give server a device serial number

So

1. Enter the serial number(I need to write in plist on iphone,But got NULL here)
2. Take the serial as a part of a new URL ex.`http://server/defaultsn_pwd.php`**?sn=1**

Because I can't write serial number in plist ,so I can't get a right URL
My URL will like this `http://server/defaultsn_pwd.php`**?sn=NULL**
It will crash my program

This is avery deadly issues ,Please help me to figure this problem out....

I trapped in this problem too long...

Comment: Does the path exist? Is localDictreadTemp nil after initWithContentsOfFile?

Comment: Should work fine. What kind of project is it ? Does it actually create the file ? Could you produce the while log ?

Comment: check for variable localFilePathTemp. var is autorelease may be it is releasing

Comment: The log result is as the comment I add after the code

Comment: The path exist,because I check it at applicationWillEnterForeground ,In my sample code ,still record it in plist.

Comment: You should store passwords in the key chain.  It's more secure.

Comment: ! How to store password in key chain ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *localDictreadTemp  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:localFilePathTemp];
```

I betcha this is the problem line. Unless you are writing a file to that location elsewhere in code, there is no file at `localFilePathTemp`. Since that file is empty, your `initWithContentsOfFile` returns a `nil` dictionary, and the rest is a chain reaction of nil objects.

try this:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:localFilePathTemp]) {
    NSLog(@"file exists at %@",localFilePathTemp);
} else NSLog(@"Some dude from the internet solved my problem, I should probably go choose his answer");
```

Comment: side note, by default the documents directory on iPhone is empty. You'll be wanting to get something out of the resource bundle, if you're including a default file in the app. `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"plist"];`

Comment: Thank you ,still try to understanding your answer

Comment: I know to include a plist file in app,But in this way I only can read not writing/read.so I have to write a plist in this way.....

Comment: I run this if condition , it goes to else ...So you are right

Comment: @WebberLai to include a file with your app, add it to the resource bundle, and then when your app first runs copy it to the documents folder.